# Bootstrap 4 vertically center text in div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this simple HTML code (with Bootstrap) :

```
<div id="accordion">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="@itm.Id">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2 border rounded text-center">
          text to center
        </div>
        <div class="col-2 border rounded text-center">Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I just want to vertically center the text "text to center" in the div, keeping the border as it is in the exemple (no height decrease).

I have tried things such `my-auto` or `align-items-middle`, also read questions asked before, but without success.

If possible I don't want to add classes (use existing bootstrap).

Here is the Fiddle : [Vertically center text](https://jsfiddle.net/7zm40xj9/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can used Flex box predefine class in Bootstrap for that:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="accordion">
  <div class="card ">
    <div class="card-header" id="@itm.Id">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2 border rounded justify-content-center  d-flex align-items-center">
          text to center
        </div>
        <div class="col-2 border rounded text-center">                           ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

For Information you can read [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/).

Comment: Thanks, I have just removed `text-center` which now has no more effect...

Answer (score 3):

Try adding `my-auto` to the first div inside the row.

```
<div class="col-2 border rounded text-center my-auto">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7zm40xj9/7/

Comment: Thanks junior but that'is exactly what I don't want (height of the div is decreased)

Answer (score 0):

**The answer is to add `d-flex align-items-center` to the element**

#### Example

If you had this:

```
<div class="col-3">
```

change it to this:

```
<div class="col-3 d-flex align-items-center>
```

Comment: This centers contained text nicely horizontally, but the question specified vertically.

Answer (score -2):

Please Use Class: **justify-content-center**